# How to run example in playframework samples folder?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I've installed Play Framework 2.0 today.(Windows 7 professional environment and JDK 1.7.0)

I have trouble with compiling and running sample application "zentasks".

Here are my steps:

1. Create new application with name zentasks
2. Eclipsify new application for IDE
3. Import source to eclipse
4. All sample code overwrites my new application.
5. Run and compile application using "play run" command

Encountered error :

```
not enough arguments for method apply: (projects: java.util.List[models.Project], user: models.User)(body: play.api.templates.Html)play.api.templates.Html in object main. Unspecified value parameter user.

In D:\play20\zentasks\app\views\index.scala.html at line 3.

1 @(message: String)
2
3 @main("Welcome to Play 2.0") { 
4    
5    @play20.welcome(message, style = "Java")
6    
7 }
```

What was wrong?

Any other configurations or dependencies needed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To run the samples, you simply change directory to the zentasks folder, then type `play run`.

You don't need to copy sources etc.

Comment: Thanks. it was tested already. but "No source available" error message raised. aren't you?

Comment: i have one of the release candidates, running on a mac, but doing the above works fine for me...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the code available in Eclipse, for example for debugging purposes, you could proceed like this:

1. In command prompt, navigate to `C:/Play-2.0/samples/java/zentasks` directory
2. Execute command `play` *-- Play console starts*
3. In the Play console, execute command `eclipsify` *-- Eclipse configuration files are generated*
4. Import the project into Eclipse with `File/Import/General/Existing project...` *-- now you have the project codes in Eclipse*
5. Execute `play run` or `play debug run` commands from command prompt (in the project directory) as usual
6. To debug, launch a remote debugger on port 9999 from Eclipse after `play debug run` command.

Comment: Thank you. Despite already try, once again, depending on how you presented to explain why.
But That's also an error. Error message head here. "Cannot init the Global object" & "Global : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0".

Comment: That may indicate the problem is related to JDK 1.7.0 you're using. Maybe you should try with JDK version 1.6 instead.

Comment: Thank you! I try downgrade(1.7->1.6) JDK version on my machine. Currently error message not raised... but, more test necessary...